# Обратиться к одному классу с разными свойствами

Tags: css

В проекте существует класс `.media-image`

1) На одной странице он отвечает за миниатюры и показывает все изо в размере 215х215

```
.media-image {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 215px;
    max-height: 215px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

2) На второй странице он должен показывать изображения на всю ширину Я пытался обратиться через родительский класс, но ничего не работает. Попробовал такие варианты:

```
.phototos > .media-image {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    max-height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Мне нужно точно указать, что для такого родителя этот класс (`media-image`) будет с такими параметрами, для другого - другой.

Но, если в втором случае поставить между классами (,) тогда слетают настройки на 215px

Comment: Ну запятая нужна для того что бы применить один набор правил к нескольким разным селекторам, в вашем примере стоит прямое наследование, да и max-width не понятно, у вас оригинал изображения 1400 пикселей? разметку покажите.

Comment: Он у вас на первой странице точно как `.media-image {` без всяких перед этим классов и т.д.(т.е. вес его не больше, чем на 2 странице?)

Comment: @sanix да вся добавка для уточнения к какому классу я обращаюсь абсолютно никак не влияет. Берется значение из чистого .media-image.
А мне надо с четко указать условие, что для такого класса этот медиа будет таким как мне надо.
Скрин [ссылка](https://vk.cc/5FtEku)

Comment: Где класс .phototos?

Comment: @НикитаСеверин это цепочка для которой условие `.phototos > .media-image {` вы хотели применить? там нету класса .phototos же...

Comment: Там есть класс phototos но он находится чутка дальше. Я не сильно понимаю в css. Просто phototos единственный класс, который отделяет настройки для media-image Он нужен именно в данном случае. Или нужно указывать полный путь от phototos до media-image?

Comment: Вот собственно для чего я писал первый комент, про прямое наследование, как долго мы к этому шли, уберите > прямое наследование.

Comment: Ну что без (>) что с ним. Не работает) Работает когда просто задаю новый параметр media-image.
Я ж и спрашиваю, стоит прописывать весь путь, там много подклассов между ними стоит.

Comment: По новому, вы используете прямое наследование, это значит что .media-image является прямым потомком .phototos, если .phototos лежит на несколько уровней выше тогда использование прямого наследования ни к чему не приведет. Если не работает значит где-то ошибка в классе или .media-image вообще не является дочерним елементом. А вообще там жесть какая-то, руки бы вот за такое по отбивать  #layers-widget-column-244 > div > div #layers-widget-column-244-671 > div > div .media-image {}  Само собой это правило будет перекрывать ваше .phototos .media-image {}  так как у него приоритет выше.

Comment: А не проще ли вспомнить БЭМ? добавь на нужных страницах модификатор `.media-image_full`, только конечно если генерацией страницы управляешь сам

Comment: @Anton Essential аля конструктор!!!!!! Часто попадаются сайты для правки собранные вот такими умельцами, это жесть..... иной раз что- бы `!important` не ставить приходится мега селектор писать.......

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось обратиться к данному css через класс всей страницы:

```
body.home .media-image  {
    min-width: 100%; !important
    max-width: 1400px; !important
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте таким образом:

```
.phototos .media-image {
   правила.
}
```

Если там такая чернь, вариантов может быть несколько, удалять вот эту жесть

```
#layers-widget-column-244 > div > div #layers-widget-column-244-671 > div > div .media-image {}
```

И добавлять (при условии если нет приоритета выше) это:

```
.media-image {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 215px;
  max-height: 215px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.phototos .media-image {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  max-height: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Либо через !important (но я бы не рекомендовал)
если там жесть станет вообще ад.

```
.phototos .media-image {
  min-width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 1400px !important;
  max-height: 800px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: В итоге  это не помоголо, конечно если бы моя верстка была лучше в разы, я  уверен ваш метод сработал бы. Все решилось через класс страницы на которой необходимы эти настройки:

`body.home .media-image  {
    min-width: 100%; !important
    max-width: 1400px; !important
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}`